# Orthogonal basis of specific span in the continuous function space

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Consider the function space of continuous functions defined on $x\in(0,1)$ with inner product $$\langle u,v\rangle =\int^{1}_{0}u(x)v(x)\,{\rm d}x.$$ Find any orthogonal basis for span $\{1,x\}$.

**My attempt**: The span $\{1,x\}$ is basically the set of all linear combinations of the two functions $f(x)=1$ and $g(x)=x$, for example $h(x)=\beta\cdot1+\alpha\cdot x$, where $\alpha,\beta$ are arbitrary scalars.

My task is to find an orthogonal basis, that is, a set of functions that can express in a linear combination any function in my span and also satisfy orthogonality, that is, $\langle u,v\rangle =0$.

So, let $\{a,b\}$ be my orthogonal basis. Since my span is simple enough, let $a=1$ and $b=c_1(1)+c_2(x)$, where $c_1,c_2$ are scalars that I want to determine.

Now I test orthogonality: $$\langle a,b\rangle =\int^{1}_{0}ab\,{\rm d}x=\int^{1}_{0}(1)(c_1+c_2x)\,{\rm d}x=c_1+c_2/2=0,$$ and so we have $c_2=2, c_1=-1$.

Thus $b=-1(1)+2(x)=2x-1$. That gives me $\{1,2x-1\}$ as the orthogonal basis of the span $\{1,x\}$.

Is my solution wrong? Have I done anything invalid? I would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: All you need to do to verify your solution is to check whether $\langle1,2x-1\rangle$ is zero. More generally, you can consult the Gram-Schmidt procedure.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown What about the wording? Do I abuse notation or am I wrong in using some specific terms? Does my solution show that I understand the ideas correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got it written up well. I'm not the best, but since you want someone to check the words you are using:

- "the span $\{ 1,x\}$ is **basically** the set of..." well yes, because the space $\operatorname{span}\{1,x\}$ is by definition exactly the set of... .
- "**and so** we have $c2=2,c1=−1$" Strictly speaking, this doesn't follow, because there are other solutions, as long as $c_1 = -c_2/2$, like $c_1 = \pi, c_2 = -2\pi$, and similarly,
- "this gives me ... as **the** orthogonal basis" there are many other choices for orthogonal bases. Even the description from the previous point doesn't describe them all.

Also, you should be using `\langle a,b\rangle` to type $\langle a,b\rangle$  instead of `<a,b>` to type $<a,b>$.